# Why is it not provisioned when running a data pipeline in a data fusion?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am using DataFusion Enterprise.

Datafusion>system admin>configuration>system compute profiles>create new profile

on this route
I set the configuration value of Master Node, Worker Node.

And I set configuration for each data pipeline. (Executor, Driver)

Now, while deploying and running the data pipeline, the provisioning state does not move on to the next startup phase.

The issue is as follows.

1.Dataproc

```
CreateCluster
asia-northest3:cdap-eventgmkt-7e769e35-182d-11b-9d9d-ce8dcdf883
service-125051400193@gcp-sa-datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Multiple Errors: - Timeout waiting for instance cdap-eventgmkt-7e769e35-182d-11b-9d9d-ce8dcdf88803-m to report in. - Timeout waiting for instance cdap-eventgmt-7769-9d-1d-1d1
```

2. Dataproc

```
DeleteCluster
asia-northest3:cdap-eventgmkt-7e769e35-182d-11b-9d9d-ce8dcdf883
service-125051400193@gcp-sa-datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Cannot delete cluster 'cdap-eventgmkt-7e769e35-182d-11eb-9d9d-ce8dcdf88803' when it has other pending delete operations.
```

In short, the data pipeline is running, but it's no longer being provisioned.

How do you solve these problems?

Thank you.

Comment: This could happen for a variety of reasons. Have you tried checking the Dataproc creation logs? They may contain more information about why it was not being created successfully. What version of Cloud Data Fusion are you running?

Comment: Did you manage to get the solution to the issue? If so, please share it in the post so other users experiencing the same issue can benefit from it. If not, follow Dennis advice and look for the Dataproc creation logs or other pipeline logs that help debug the issue. Share any logs you suspect may be the reason so we can help and consider contacting Google Cloud Platform Support if you are unable to debug it by yourself.